# Error with defining ref class type in class library

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am following DrDobbs [article](https://www.drdobbs.com/ccli-by-example-getting-started/184401899).

It creates a Point class in a class library but when I do this, it doesn't compile.

```
namespace Point
{
    public ref class Point
    {
    }
}
```

The error is:

> error CS1031: Type expected

But that doesn't tell much.

If I remove the `ref` keyword, it compiles fine. I wonder what am I missing?

Comment: I think you're confusing your C# and C++/CLI.

Comment: @rfmodulator From the article `To create the Point project, select File|New|Project|Empty Project. (Do not choose "Class Library.")` I followed that and even tried class library but same result. It doesn't ask to create empty CLR project but maybe it means that? But it should have stated that.

Comment: Only structs can use `ref` not classes. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/ref#ref-struct-types

Comment: @rfmodulator It does work in empty CLR project. I guess that's what the article meant but it doesn't say that explicitly.

Answer (score -1):

The article in question didn't say this explicitly but the project created should be CLR project (either empty CLR project and CLR class library).

It makes sense as the project settings talked about in the article applies to C++ not C#.